# How to divide a list and delete half of it in python

Tags: python, django

i need help.
Please How can I divide a list in Python, into two equal parts and delete one part. Then assign one part to a new variable.

example

```
list = ['name', 'can', 'she', 'men', 'them', 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

How then can I delete half part of this list and assign half to a new variable

```
new_list = ['name', 'can', 'she', 'men', 'them']
```

Comment: You shouldn't call your variables `list`, or any other built-in type or function.

Comment: if order doesn't matter, new_list = list(set(dup_list)) will work

Comment: Your edit completely changes the question and invalidates the existing answer. I've rolled back the change. I'd suggest asking a new question instead.

Answer (score 6):

You just need a slice:

```
new_list = list[:len(list)//2]
```

Comment: For Python 3 needs to be `//2` to make sure result of division is integer.

Comment: Good point; that syntax has been supported since Python 2.2, so may as well be explicit about it.